# Label a layer by excluding specific features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I would need to label a layer excluding specific features based on the value of an attribute, i.e.
[image]
[image]

I would not want to appear the labels like `'xxxxxx_FIUME_xxxxx'` or `'FIUME_xxxxx'` etc.
I tried using the rule-based option with an expression like `"NOME" NOT LIKE '% [_]FIUME%'` but without success (all features are found).
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: For clarificatipn: Would you like the small rivers to simply be labeled "Fiume" or to have no label at all?

Comment: "NOME" NOT LIKE '%FIUME%'  doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, 1 - no label at all. 2 - the values that I have to exclude have format 'xxxxxx_FIUME_xxxxx' or 'FIUME_xxxxx' or 'xxxxxx_CANALE_xxxxx' and so on but there may be valid values like 'FIUME TEMO'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose rulebased labeling, you can use for example the following expression as a filter to rule out all labels containing "fiume"

```
NOT(regexp_match("NOME",'FIUME'))
```

This gives you all rivers not containing the string "fiume", then you simply tell QGis how to label these.
Then you also have to "catch" all the rivers containing the "fiume"-string

```
regexp_match("NOME",'FIUME')
```

And now tell QGis to not to label these, or maybe label with the same shortened expression for all small rivers.

Comment: thanks, therefore the rule to insert would be: NOT(regexp_match("NOME",'FIUME')) and if I had more values to exclude in the same rule it could be NOT(regexp_match("NOME",'FIUME_','CANALE_'))?

Comment: Nope, you can only check for one argument/string with regexp. You'd have to build subrules in order to check for other strings.

Comment: OK, seems to work with NOT  ((  regexp_match(  "NOME" , 'FIUME_' )) OR (regexp_match(  "NOME" , 'CANALE_' ))), Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, OR is the most obvious answer^^ glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Other way is:

```
"NOME" != 'FIUME_' AND "NOME" != 'CANALE_'
```